# make element visible only if scrolled down or page higher than video, CSS only

Tags: css

I want absolute element appear only when page is scrolled down, or at least when page height is higher than window height.

Is this possible with pure CSS? How?

example code:

```
<body>
    content...
    <button id="return">return to top</button>
</body>
```

want to show `#return` only if 1 page is higher than window OR 2 scrollbar is visible OR 3 even better scrollbar is visible and scrolled down

Comment: No...CSS has no idea where your elements are in the viewport. You need JS.

Comment: sticky can probably do this but you need to be more specific and share you actual code and layout

Comment: using position absolute, and top 110vh is an half solution proposed here down, for now is the better solution also. Only point is, if I have a semi-blank page that is 50vh, how could I avoid to show the item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea where the element will appear after a small scroll and will sticky to the bottom:

```css
p {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  position: relative; /* relative to the body */
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110vh; /* defined when the element will appear */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* needed to push the sticky element down */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  /* to hide element if content is short*/
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
}

.fixed>div {
  /* stick to the bottom */
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background: red;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ac risus ac est pulvinar finibus cursus non augue. Proin turpis tortor, dapibus vel metus eget, fermentum aliquam diam. Quisque sodales est sed diam mollis dictum. Aliquam ut volutpat nisi.
  Aenean luctus turpis in malesuada malesuada. Praesent non ligula ut ligula feugiat convallis porttitor nec leo. Integer vel risus eget metus viverra ultrices vel vel enim. Sed vitae laoreet ex. Fusce tristique feugiat odio non consequat. Sed bibendum
  tempor est, sed vestibulum ex aliquet quis. Nam libero quam, laoreet at elementum in, scelerisque vel ex. Vivamus ac purus eget orci vehicula gravida. Aliquam eleifend felis eget porttitor sollicitudin. Donec ut sodales eros. Sed a eros urna.
  
  tempor est, sed vestibulum ex aliquet quis. Nam libero quam, laoreet at elementum in, scelerisque vel ex. Vivamus ac purus eget orci vehicula gravida. Aliquam eleifend felis eget porttitor sollicitudin. Donec ut sodales eros. Sed a eros urna.
</p>
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="banner">some content here</div>
</div>
```

With some fading effect:

```css
p {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  position: relative; /* relative to the body */
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110vh; /* defined when the element will appear */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* needed to push the sticky element down */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  /*fading*/
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent,#fff 200px);
          mask:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent,#fff 200px);
}

.fixed>div {
  /* stick to the bottom */
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background: red;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ac risus ac est pulvinar finibus cursus non augue. Proin turpis tortor, dapibus vel metus eget, fermentum aliquam diam. Quisque sodales est sed diam mollis dictum. Aliquam ut volutpat nisi.
  Aenean luctus turpis in malesuada malesuada. Praesent non ligula ut ligula feugiat convallis porttitor nec leo. Integer vel risus eget metus viverra ultrices vel vel enim. Sed vitae laoreet ex. Fusce tristique feugiat odio non consequat. Sed bibendum
  tempor est, sed vestibulum ex aliquet quis. Nam libero quam, laoreet at elementum in, scelerisque vel ex. Vivamus ac purus eget orci vehicula gravida. Aliquam eleifend felis eget porttitor sollicitudin. Donec ut sodales eros. Sed a eros urna.
  
  
  tempor est, sed vestibulum ex aliquet quis. Nam libero quam, laoreet at elementum in, scelerisque vel ex. Vivamus ac purus eget orci vehicula gravida. Aliquam eleifend felis eget porttitor sollicitudin. Donec ut sodales eros. Sed a eros urna.
</p>
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="banner">some content here</div>
</div>
```

---

To avoid the extra scroll when the content is short here is a trick using `min()` (it won't work on Firefox for now)

```css
p {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  position: relative; /* relative to the body */
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: min(100%,110vh); /* defined when the element will appear */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* needed to push the sticky element down */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  /*fading*/
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent,#fff 200px);
          mask:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent,#fff 200px);
}

.fixed>div {
  /* stick to the bottom */
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background: red;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ac risus ac est pulvinar finibus cursus non augue. Proin turpis tortor, dapibus vel metus eget, fermentum aliquam diam. Quisque sodales est sed diam mollis dictum. Aliquam ut volutpat nisi.
  Aenean luctus turpis in malesuada malesuada. Praesent non ligula ut ligula feugiat convallis porttitor nec leo. Integer vel risus eget metus viverra ultrices vel vel enim. Sed vitae laoreet ex. Fusce tristique feugiat odio non consequat. Sed bibendum
  tempor est, sed vestibulum ex aliquet quis. Nam libero quam, laoreet at elementum in, scelerisque vel ex. Vivamus ac purus eget orci vehicula gravida. Aliquam eleifend felis eget porttitor sollicitudin. Donec ut sodales eros. Sed a eros urna.
  
  
  tempor est, sed vestibulum ex aliquet quis. Nam libero quam, laoreet at elementum in, scelerisque vel ex. Vivamus ac purus eget orci vehicula gravida. Aliquam eleifend felis eget porttitor sollicitudin. Donec ut sodales eros. Sed a eros urna.
</p>
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="banner">some content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: using position absolute, and top 110vh is a solution, for now is the better solution also. Only point is, if I have a semi-blank page that is 50vh, how could I avoid to show the item?

Comment: @LucaC. it was a bit complex that what I expected. Check the update now